# Getting device ID to show Admob Interstitial Ads

Tags: java, android, android-studio, interstitial

I have previously used Admob, but only to display Banner Ads. Now on my latest App I'd like to use Interstitial Ads, but I have some doubts about it.

According to the documentation, in order to request for a new Ad, I need to do something like this:

```
 AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("Device_ID")
                .build();
```

The problem is that I don't know how to get the device ID programatically, since I guess it's a different one on each device. What I've done so far to dislpay Interstitial test ads on my device is calling the `.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)` method. So it's pretty much working fine on my device.

The main problem is that I want to be able to display interstitial ads on multiple devices, but I sincerely don't know how to get the ID programatically to get it to work in any device.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I usually use on my apps :

```
public static String getMD5(String inputText){
     String md5 = "";
     try{
        MessageDigest digester = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        digester.update(inputText.getBytes());
        md5 = new BigInteger(1, digester.digest()).toString(16);
     }
     catch(Exception e){}
     return md5;
}



public String getDeviceId(){
     String androidID = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
     String deviceID = getMD5(androidID).toUpperCase();
     return deviceID;
}
```

Comment: I was missunderstanding it all about Interstitial Ads, but now I see how does it work thanks to your code. Thanks a lot! It's a fantastic answer!